# Surjective homomorphism from indefinite orthogonal group $O(p,q)$ to ${\{-1,1}\}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

For each $A\in O(p,q)$, we may write

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} &A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then it is said that $\det(A_{11})\neq 0$ and $\det(A_{22})\neq 0$.

> Furthermore, the map 
>   $$O(p,q)\rightarrow{\{-1,1}\}^2,\quad A\mapsto(\operatorname{sgn}(\det(A_{11})), \operatorname{sgn}(\det(A_{22})))$$
>   is a surjective homomorphism.

I see that one can prove that this map is a surjective homomorphism by exploiting continuity and the topology of $O(p,q)$.

However, I am looking for a proof in which one uses matrix algebra and the determinant function.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you denote $O(p,q)$?

Comment: @Bernard It's the indefinite orthogonal group.

Comment: Is $\{-1,1\}^2=\{(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1)\}$ or?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya what you said is correct

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could summarize (or perhaps provide a reference for) the topological proof that you refer to.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom chapter 7 of Matrices: Theory and Applications by Dennis Serre includes the topological proof.

Comment: @Lee all right, thanks

Comment: @Lee It would suffice to argue that $\|A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}\| < 1$ for some choice of matrix-norm.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you provide a brief explanation on how that is?

Comment: @Lee Suppose that $B$ is another (conformally partitioned) element of $O(p,q)$. We have
$$
\det([AB]_{11}) = \det(A_{11}B_{11} + A_{12}B_{21})\\
= \det(A_{11})\det(B_{11})\det(I_p + [A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}][B_{21}B_{11}^{-1}]).
$$
If $\|M\| \leq 1$, then $\det(I + M) \geq 0$.

Comment: @Lee From the definition, it's easy to get $A_{11}^TA_{11} = I + A_{21}^TA_{21}$ so that $\|A_{11}\| > \|A_{21}\|$. However, I don't see a way to leverage that to relate $A_{11}$ and $A_{12}$.

Comment: @Lee we also have $A_{12} = A_{11}^{-T}A_{21}^TA_{22}$, maybe that's helpful somehow.

Comment: @omnomnomnom thank you very much, I think I've got it now

Comment: It's in Russian and perhaps a bit obscure, but there's a proof based on matrix algebra in the book [Clifford Algebra and Spinors](http://www.mi-ras.ru/noc/11_12/cllifalg10.12.11.pdf) by Shirokov, page 89-90. I don't know Russian myself but it's not too hard to follow. I would write it up but I don't have time right now. It should also be in Lester, "Orthochronous subgroups of O(p,q)" (1993), although I don't have access to that.

Comment: @echinodermata Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $M$ lies in $O(p,q)$ if, by definition, $M^t D M=D$, where $D=\pmatrix{ I_p & 0 \cr 0 & -I_q}.$

Assume further that $M$ is block diagonal, so $A_{12}=A_{21}=0$.Then $M$ lies in $O(p,q)$ if and only if $A_{11}^tA_{11}=I_p$ and $A_{22}^tA_{22}=I_q$, that is $A_{11}\in O(p)$ and $A_{22}\in O(q)$.

But it is known (and very easy anyway) to find matrices in $O(n)$ with determinant $1$ and $-1$ for any $n\geq 1$, so you get the desired surjectivity.

Comment: Thank you but do you have any clue on how to show that the map is a homomorphism?